# Android Reverse Tethering With Broken Radio

Tags: networking, vpn, android, adb, reverse-tethering

I have exactly the problem mentioned in this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/issues/436#issuecomment-1228934396):

> For my use case, this is a problem that cannot be worked around by connecting to WiFi. My phone's antenna, or possibly a related component, is broken (water damage). Everything on the phone works well except mobile data, WiFi, Bluetooth, and GPS. Functions that require wireless connectivity are completely non-operative.
>
> Gnirehtet works great on my phone for apps like Chrome; I can browse the web just fine when it's running. Other apps that seem to be trying to intelligently detect when the phone is "connected", including most messaging apps, still aren't functional even with Gnirehtet connected.
>
> I'm on Android 12.
>
> I would be very curious to hear if anyone knows what might need to be done in Gnirehtet to make it work for my use case, where the workaround of connecting to (any) WiFi network is simply not an option.

For a reverse tethering app that connects your Android device to the Internet (see [gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet)), how do I make it so that apps on a device with a broken radio antenna (no wifi, mobile connection etc) that query for connectivity are responded to with a connection available message.

I have tried adding `setUnderlyingNetworks(...)` when the `VpnService` is set up on `gnirehtet` but was not successful.

I have also searched for an `adb` command that might be able to fake a connection available response to apps on a device to little success.

Comment: Apps shouldn't care where the network connection comes from. As long as you follow the instructions in your own link it should theoretically work without complications. And keep in mind: *Questions about Android devices are off-topic for Super User and should be asked on android.stackexchange.com unless they specifically involve interaction with a computer.* Whatever happens or doesn't within Android and/or Android apps is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto Will ask this question on android.stackexchange.com. I was not aware that existed.

Comment: BTW, it does not work and there are a few others with the same problem. Issue is that it is likely those apps are just querying the system for connectivity and given that the antenna is broken, this immediately returns a no-connectivity message disregarding the reverse tether.